# Is there a way to change resolution on a Note 4?

Tags: screen-resolution, samsung-galaxy-note-4

Currently everything is huge, I would like to know if I can change my resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have root,  you can edit your **build.prop** file. There even apps from the Play Store to do that for you. When changing LCD density (DPI), be cautious to what you change it to.  Lower the value too much and items will be unreadable, also making the system unstable with certain apps. The Play Store might fail to work. As with everything, perform a backup in case of instabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Use DPI changer apps like [Textdroider DPI](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=es&id=com.texdroider.texdroider_dpi), but you'd need root access for it.